# Select.pdf Avoid displaying 'Demo Version - Select.Pdf SDK'

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I successfully installed NuGet package 'Select.pdf". When I run the website, I see "Demo Version - Select.Pdf SDK" displaying at the end, What can I do to avoid this ? It's free tool, available from NuGet.

```
SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf converter = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();
SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl("http://www.cnn.com");
doc.Save(Response, false, "test.pdf");
doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have installed the wrong package (Full Version):

[`Select.Pdf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.Pdf/)

The **free** (Community) version is only the Html Converter:

[`Select.HtmlToPdf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf/)

Keep in mind, that the free version [only supports up to 5 pages](http://selectpdf.com/community-edition/).

Comment: Hmm, I thought I installed correct package. Can you please let me know what NuGet package should I install ?

Comment: it is linked in the answer

Comment: Thank you, it works. I used Select.HtmlToPdf as mentioned, and copied Select.Html.dep to Bin directory from packages folder, and it works, thanks for all the help !